# Laravel multiple table join saved to a variable and running a foreach against it (search function)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I presently have 3 tables: Shows, Genres and Show_Genre (associates the two).  I have a search form that submits a series of checkboxes with values into an array based on what genres they selected.  Presently I want to associate the Shows table and the Genres table into a variable and run a query against it once for every genre checkbox selected.  Then, once the selection is filtered, I can display the resulting Show objects that matched the users parameters.

My present setup is the following

```
public function searchShows(SearchRequest $request)
{
    //$ShowsWithGenres give a collection inside a collection which I can't seem to even access its values without doing a bunch of ugly code using count() in a for loop
    $ShowsWithGenres = Show::with('genres')->get();
    $genres = $request->name;
    if(isset($genres))
    {
        foreach($genres as $genre)
        {
            //iterate against the selection repeatedly reducing the number of results
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `whereHas()` and `whereIn`.

Perhaps something like this should do it:

```
$shows = Show::whereHas('genres', function($q) use($genre_ids)
{
    $q->whereIn('id', $genre_ids);

})->get();
```

EDIT
Try this, however I'm unsure about the performance.

```
$query= Show::query();

foreach($genre_ids as $id){
    $query->whereHas('genres', function($q) use($id)
        {
            $q->where('id', $id);
        })
}
$shows = $query->get();
```

Comment: This works, however, it seems to return all shows that have just 1 of the genres and not a limited 'you must have all genres in $genres' as I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eloquents `whereHas()` function you can query results based on the relation's data. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations

```
public function searchShows(SearchRequest $request)
{
    // Start a query (but don't execute it at this point as we may want to add more)
    $query = Show::with('genres');
    $genreNames = (array) $request->name;

    // Check there are some genre names, if theres not any it'll cause an SQL syntax error
    if (count($genreNames) > 0)
    {
        $query->whereHas('genres', function($subQuery) use ($genreNames)
        {
            $subQuery->whereIn('genre_name', $genreNames);
        }
    }

    // Finally execute the query. $shows now contains only shows with the genres that the user has searched for, if they didn't search with any genres, then it contains all the results.
    $shows = $query->get();
}
```